# How to query only specific keys as list of map from large list of map couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I want to query couchbase data using plain SQL query from the couchbase console.

The oop schema will be like this.

Original:

```
class travel-sample{
      //all properties
      List<Schedule> schedule;
}

class Schedule{
    //all properties
}
```

Need to project travel-sample like this in a separate class:

```
 class travel-sample-another{
      //some properties
      List<Schedule> schedule;
}

class Schedule-another{
    //some properties
}
```

Following are documents:

Document:

```
[
  {
    "travel-sample": {
      "airline": "AF",
      "airlineid": "airline_137",
      "destinationairport": "MRS",
      "distance": 2881.617376098415,
      "equipment": "320",
      "id": 10000,
      "schedule": [
        {
          "day": 4,
          "flight": "AF818",
          "utc": "08:02:00"
        },
        {
          "day": 5,
          "flight": "AF967",
          "utc": "11:33:00"
        },
        {
          "day": 5,
          "flight": "AF730",
          "utc": "19:42:00"
        }
      ],
      "sourceairport": "TLV",
      "stops": 0,
      "type": "route"
    }
  }
]
```

How to query to get results like this:

```
[
  {
    "travel-sample": {
      "airline": "AF",
      "airlineid": "airline_137",
      "destinationairport": "MRS",
      "schedule": [
                    {
          "flight": "AF818",
          "utc": "08:02:00"
        },
        {
          "flight": "AF967",
          "utc": "11:33:00"
        },
        {
          "flight": "AF730",
          "utc": "19:42:00"
        }
      ],
      "sourceairport": "TLV",
      "type": "route"
    }
  }
]
```

We could see `day` property is not in the array of the map for schedule and so on. I want exact this format efficiently. I am new to the couchbase. Maybe UNNEST, NEST or Iteration can help, however, I couldn't get the way to retrieve exactly this result. Just plain sql query will be good for me. I will take care of other stuff. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I got it. I was looking for something like this: ```select id, airlineid, type, sourceairport, airline, ARRAY {sc.day, sc.flight} for sc in schedule end as schedule from `travel-sample` where schedule is not null limit 100;```